# Sudden failure in DNN development environment

Tags: dotnetnuke, webmatrix-3

I've been working on a mixed desktop-and-web based solution for quite some time now. My local development environment was using VS2013-Pro, a recent DNN version (7.3, I think), Webmatrix 3, IIS Express 8.0, and SQL Server 2014 running on Windows 7 on Parallels on my Mac. Everything is up-to-date, all SP's installed, etc.

I developed a couple of REST webservices and a DNN module, and it's all been humming along and working really--shockingly--amazingly(!) well, when very suddenly:

I hit the DNN site and Webmatrix crashes and I get an error that says "IIS Worker process has stopped." And hasn't worked since. The debugger gives me the message "Unhandled exception at 0x762CC42D (KernelBase.dll) in iisexpress.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0x80131530, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x72F90000)."

I did not change anything, this started in the middle of a coding session. It worked fine for months, and then it just didn't any more.

I researched a bit and found several suggestions, none worked (delete cache folder, uninstall/reinstall). I find another post that mentions that Webmatrix is a dead product now. I try just to set up same site in IIS (following DNN's own instructions and a couple of other very similar sets I found). Still can't make site load--even the front page.

I download a fresh DNN install package (7.4 now) and try from scratch. Now when I try to load the site I get Visual Studio's Just In Time Debugger telling me an unhandled Win32 exception in w3wp.exe [2648]. I try running the debugger but it doesn't actually give any information.

I feel like other than the Webmatrix/DNN installation I've always had a lot of trouble getting DNN running locally, even following the directions to the letter. I need it running locally because I work disconnected a lot.

Am I missing something big here? Is anyone else having trouble all of a sudden? I've spent the better part of 4 days unistalling, reinstalling, tinkering, and can come up with nothing.

-Tim

Comment: What is the error you get in IIS when you try to bring up the site?

Comment: @DotNetNuclear:
When I try to load the website, after about 30 seconds I get a small window that says "An unhandled win32 exception occurred in w3wp.exe [2672]" and a message that the JIT debugger was launched without necessary security permissions. Would I like to debug it?
Yes | Debug with new instance of VS2013 | Attach the Application Pool process. Message this time (sometimes I get nothing) is:
Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEFCD6B16D (KernelBase.dll) in w3wp.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0xFFFFFFFF80131530, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x000007FEF7250000).

Comment: Summary of IIS configuration:
Website name: dnndev, http:*:80:dnndev.me
Application pool named dnndev, v4.0, Integrated
Permissions on the website root folder are set to modify for IIS AppPool/dnndev.
The database connection string in web.config works fine.
When I do the Test Connection, the Authentication works but I get a 'cannot verify' warning on the Authorization.

Comment: I might try to repair the .NET framework by downloading the latest full 4.5.2 offline installer.

Comment: So I tried that, and no luck. I took a step further back and uninstalled IIS and SQL Server, and obliterated DNN. Started from scratch following DNN's instructions for setting up a development environment (http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/setting-up-your-module-development-environment).
Now...it serves up the installation wizard, but without any stylesheets...and this basically makes it unworkable (as it doesn't recognize some text as buttons).
I've verified that permissions on the entire DNN tree are set the same (and correctly), and that the stylesheets referenced are present.

Comment: I feel like this is a problem that I've had before as well, but I cannot find any resources to help work through it.
I have followed the directions on the setup page to-the-letter, even with a friend looking over my shoulder to keep me honest. Once I have an environment set up everything always goes swimmingly, but for some reason, every time--only with DNN--my modest server configuration skills seem to fail me.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after uninstalling everything (down to the metal, everything to do with SQL server, IIS, Webmatrix, and the recent .net framework updates) and then reinstalling them, I've been up and running for a week or so now. I've disabled Windows update, I think it was something in there that got me in this position in the first place. Not a great long-term solution, but it'll do for now.